# Elasticsearch dsl Term Filter not working with string Field

Tags: django, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am trying to apply `term` filter elastic search index data using `elasticsearch_dsl` python client but it's not working with string field.

This is my ES index data:

```
s = Search(using=es, index='idx_object', doc_type='ip').source(include=['id', 'status', 'username'])
```

> [{u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'79', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'jackie@example.com', u'id': 79}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'84', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'julia@example.com', u'id': 84}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'73', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'brad@example.com', u'id': 73}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'82', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'julia@example.com', u'id': 82}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'65', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'george@example.com', u'id': 65}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'78', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'julia@example.com', u'id': 78}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'62', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'brad@example.com', u'id': 62}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'96', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'brad@example.com', u'id': 96}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'70', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'brad@example.com', u'id': 70}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}, {u'_score': 1.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'80', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'george@example.com', u'id': 80}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}]

Now if I apply a filter in id integer field it's working.

```
s = Search(using=es, index='idx_object', doc_type='ip').source(include=['id', 'status', 'username']).filter("term", id=79)
```

Output:

> [{u'_score': 0.0, u'_type': u'ip', u'_id': u'79', u'_source': {u'status': u'PUBLISHED', u'username': u'jackie@example.com', u'id': 79}, u'_index': u'idx_object'}]

Now if I apply filter on username string field its not working:

```
s = Search(using=es, index='idx_object', doc_type='ip').source(include=['id', 'status', 'username']).filter("term", username='jackie@example.com')
```

Output:

> []

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are `username` field is a `text field`. `Term` query looks for exact match i.e it will look for a token with **jackie@example.com**
in `reverse index`

In case you are using `ES 5.x`, you can try changing your query to

```
s = Search(using=es, index='idx_object', doc_type='ip').source(include=['id', 'status', 'username']).filter("term", username.keyword='jackie@example.com')
```

In case ES version < `5.x`.

- If you want exact match You can use [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-field-search.html) for creating a `raw` version of your field `username` and then apply `term` query on that field.

Hope this helps!